apply matplotlib 2D screen space transformation to data

import numpy as np

def getAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    """
    Calculate the angle in degrees between three points.

    Parameters:
        x1, y1: Coordinates of the first point.
        x2, y2: Coordinates of the second point.
        x3, y3: Coordinates of the third point.

    Returns:
        float: Angle between the vectors formed by the three points in degrees.
    """
    # Calculate the vectors between the points
    v1 = np.array([x1 - x2, y1 - y2])
    v2 = np.array([x3 - x2, y3 - y2])

    # Calculate the dot product of the two vectors
    dot_product = np.dot(v1, v2)

    # Calculate the magnitudes of the vectors
    v1_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(v1)
    v2_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(v2)

    # Calculate the cosine of the angle between the vectors
    cosine_angle = dot_product / (v1_magnitude * v2_magnitude)

    # Calculate the angle in radians
    angle_radians = np.arccos(cosine_angle)

    # Convert radians to degrees
    angle_degrees = np.degrees(angle_radians)

    return angle_degrees

a = (1, -0.302825927734375)
b = (2, -0.24786376953125)
c = (3, -0.304443359375)

print(getAngle(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], c[0], c[1]))

The angle is 173.6157464479552°. Visually if you see the captured image of the plot, the angle between points is around 90°. No scaling is applied to view just zoomed in. Matplotlib applies some kind of 2D transformation in screen space to the data before the actual plot. I need to know
that transformation calculation, to get the screen space coordinates, also I'm looking for a generic solution rather than matplotlib dependent.
From the above image, pixels coordinates are a = (60,220), b = (133,140), c = (270,220) and if you calculate the angle in between them, it's roughly 102°. I need this angle from actual points.
